# Ajax-Compatible middleware for express/connect

Tags: node.js, express, connect, csrf

As it says in the title, I'm looking for a middleware for [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) or [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) that will enable me to make `csrf`-safe requests.

The [csrf-middleware in connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-csrf.html) creates a new token per request, which makes `POST`-requests over Ajax not very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only create a new CSRF token per session instead of per request or something, you could always take advantage of the fact that that Connect's csrf middleware lets you pass in your own token generation function. For example:

```
connect.csrf(function (req) {
  if (!req.session['myCsrfToken']) {
    req.session['myCsrfToken'] = ... // generate token somehow
  }

  return req.session['myCsrfToken'];
});
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks. Do you, per chance, have a link to an article about the secure token generation via node?

Comment: Connect generates its tokens using the `crypto` module. You can see the implementation at https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/csrf.js (look for `exports.uid`). You can do the same thing the connect-csrf module does by using `require('connect').utils.uid(24)`.